# Is there a use for a separate [demangling] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I noticed a question regarding demangling and noticed that there was no [[demangling]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/demangling) tag and only one questions tagged [[demangler]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/demangler) which doesn't really fit the tag naming scheme. Most of the demangling questions seem to miss any kind mangling tag.

Three retags later, however, I noticed [[name-mangling]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/name-mangling) (currently 23 questions) and am now indecisive... most questions are rather specific about *demangling*, but that subject is a subset of *name mangling*.

Do we need a specific [demangling], or keep both and tag where appropriate?

Something else? Opinions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that demangling falls under [name-mangling], and I say to just use that tag.